# HTML Audio - how can i detect if a stream is available?

Tags: javascript, html, events, audio, stream

I want to use the HTML audio tag to play a webradio which is only one time per week for 3 hours available.

When the user comes to the view and the radio isn't available, i want to show a message to the user showing what happened.

When the browser loads the code, i see in the developer console in Google Chrome that the request is "canceled" if the stream isn't available.

Does somebody know the event which is triggered when the loading of the stream is canceled? I tried some events: abort, error, waiting, suspend, ended - nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

**About "When the user comes to the view and the radio isn't available, i want to show a message to the user showing what happened."**

Audio tags can be a list of sources, that will be loaded in cascade if the previous one fails.

Example:

```
<audio controls>
<source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio tag. <- is that message enough?
</audio>
```

**About "some events: abort, error, waiting, suspend, ended"**

I can't see "cancel" in that list :-) and i am wondering how did you tried those events at all.

Ended will not be triggered if never played it. You got canceled because the connection was not made. Rather than having a cancel event, cancelled is the result of not being connected, that's why you can't see any event at all.

For questions about events, look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

In example, ended only is triggered once is loaded and reachs the end of stream. Suspend seems to be only available once it has tried to load but you suspend it before start to play.

I really guess that you cannot detect the cancelled once a media stream is not available.

You may be able to just make an http query to the stream, in order to detect if it's available or not. I found an example of that here [How to check if an audio stream is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33039670/2480481). The better if you do it with the xmlhttp requester in javascript along the tags.

Answer (score -1):

I completely understand this may not be what you want to hear but: If you know the time each week the show is on - can't you just hide the player/redirect the user if the date and time is not within the bounds of the show itself?

Can you give some code context on this or a URL?
It *sounds* to me like Chrome is cancelling the request and not the stream cancelling it - for example I have seen this when trying to pre-load audio in the past.

Comment: I `-1`'d this as it's better suited as a comment.

Comment: Yes, this isn't the solution which i look for. The stream isn't every week available and also not at the same time or same weekday. It's a liveradio of a football game.

It is definitly not a problem of google chrome.