# How to check if an audio stream is correct?

Tags: python, audio

I will be using internet streams for a DYI alarm clock and would like to check if a given stream is correct. By correct I mean that the streamed data is there and if it actually carries audio.

The "is there" part is taken care by a simple call:

```
import requests
urls = [
    'http://statslive.infomaniak.ch/playlist/energy90s/energy90s-high.mp3/playlist.pls',
    'http://stream.chantefrance.com/stream_chante_france.mp3',
    'http://streaming.radio.rtl2.fr/rtl2-1-44-128',
    'http://fakestream.example.com'
    ]

for url in urls:
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    except Exception as e:
        print('failed to get stream: {e}'.format(e=e))
    else:
        if r.ok:
            content_type = r.headers['content-type']
            print('stream {url} is of type {content_type}'.format(url=url, content_type=content_type))
        else:
            print('error getting the stream: {error}'.format(error=r.text))
    r = None    # I do not know how I should really 'close' the stream
```

This output indicates what kind of stream I have, if any

```
stream http://statslive.infomaniak.ch/playlist/energy90s/energy90s-high.mp3/playlist.pls is of type audio/x-scpls
stream http://stream.chantefrance.com/stream_chante_france.mp3 is of type audio/mpeg
stream http://streaming.radio.rtl2.fr/rtl2-1-44-128 is of type audio/mpeg
failed to get stream: ('Connection aborted.', gaierror(11001, 'getaddrinfo failed'))
```

I now would like to check (a sample of?) the stream to make sure there is audio data in. This is to avoid to have a correct stream but which would broadcast for a reason or another nothing (remember that this is for an alarm clock and therefore production-critical data :)).

**How to check for this kind of information?**

I saw that there is [sndhdr](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/sndhdr.html) but it seems to be targetted towards full-fledged audio files.

Comment: I guess the best way would be to check headers

Comment: @Andrey: which headers? I already check the response headers (with content-type), as indicated in the code I posted

Comment: file headers, every audio file has well defined headers: http://www.datavoyage.com/mpgscript/mpeghdr.htm

Comment: I agree, but this is not a file but a stream

Comment: it still has to have headers in place to check otherwise how players know how to play it?

Comment: @Andrey: they get a continuous stream of data with some meta-data (RDS etc.) and they probably rely on the content-type headers. `mpg123` for instance need to be told when certain formats are used (even though it supports them)

Comment: you can't just start randomly playing mp3, it is split into frames and each frame has header, without parsing it player can't play that frame, there is essential information like bitrate http://www.mp3-tech.org/programmer/frame_header.html

Comment: Ah OK - thanks for the information. I would then need to decode the frame to check if there is something more than silence then (the content-type will be an indication of the overall healthiness of the stream)

Comment: Yes you need to detect frame to look into actual audio content.

Comment: fyi, how to close your stream: [requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow) and [contextlib.closing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing)